# How can I parse the variable number of arguments to a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to pass a variable number of arguments to a function,  the first argument represents a command, and the remaining arguments represent the arguments to the command. For example:

```
def do(*argv):
    command = argv[0]

    match command:
        case "doNothing":
            print("do nothing")
        case "create":
            arg = argv[1]
            print(arg)
        case "add":
            arg1 = argv[1]
            arg2 = argv[2]
            print(arg1 + arg2)
        case default:
            return "something wrong with the input to do()"

do("create", [1,2])
```

and run it

```
$ python ./my.py
  File "/home/t/my.py", line 8
    match command:
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I parse the variable number of arguments?

Comment: I think you meant to do `command = argv[0:]` but then why slice the `argv` if you are going to take all arrays anyways.

Comment: Use the `head, *tail` pattern of unpacking iterables: `cmd, *args = argv`

Comment: If you're getting a syntax error with `match command` or `match argv[0]` then you don't have Python 3.10.

Comment: @ddejohn could you elaborate both comments? How can I get argv[1]? Why is it not?

Comment: @Tim it's not clear what you're trying to do. Are you trying to split the args and the command? Then do `cmd, *args = argv` and proceed with your logic. If you're trying to solve a syntax error, then you likely aren't using the correct version of Python for structural pattern matching.

Comment: @ddejohn. correct, mine is 3.9. What can I use instead?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html

Comment: I recommend looking at the [official tutorial](https://peps.python.org/pep-0636/), as well. This is a brand new feature in Python.

Answer (score -3):

**for Python >= 3.10**:
there is `match - case` support. see example in [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#pep-634-structural-pattern-matching)

```py
msg = 2
match msg:
    case 0:
        print('no')
    case 1:
        print('no')
    case 2:
        print('yes')

#output:==> "yes"
```

---

**for Python < 3.10**:
it does NOT support "swich - case" like Javascript

```
match ____:
    case ___:
      ....
```

instead, use `if - elif - else`
try this:

```
def do(*argv):
    command = argv[0]
    if command == "doNothing":
        print("do nothing")
    elif command == "create":
        arg = argv[1]
        print(arg)
    elif command == "add":
        arg1 = argv[1]
        arg2 = argv[2]
        print(arg1 + arg2)
    else:
        return "something wrong with the input to do()"

do("create", [1,2])
# argv is ["create", [1,2]]
# so, 
#       arg = argv[1]
#        print(arg)
#
# will print [1, 2]
```

Comment: It does in 3.10 and later.

Comment: @CrazyChucky, no it doesn't . not like javascript. I think you mean implementing it with a dict like this https://www.upgrad.com/blog/how-to-implement-switch-case-functions-in-python/

Comment: If I am wrong, please give me a working example

Comment: It is not exactly like in JavaScript, but it was definitely added in 3.10. https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#pep-634-structural-pattern-matching

Comment: To clarify: while it can do more than JavaScript's switch/case, it can also be used to accomplish the same thing. See [the simple example](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#simple-pattern-match-to-a-literal) in the linked release notes.

Comment: thanks! I haven't known about this feature as I  was using Python 3.9